# Solving a system of coupled non-linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the following (the derivatives are wrt $t$):

$$ x'(t)  =yz $$

$$  y'(t) = -xz $$

$$ z'(t)  = xy  $$

Any hints on how to solve this ? (and how can I make use of the hint  $xx' + 2yy'+zz' = 0$ suggested in the comments ?)

**Edit:** with the initial conditions
$$ \text{ @ } t= 0,  \ \  \left(  x(0) = s ,\ \  y(0) = 0 , \ \ z(0) = -e^{-s} \right) , s \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: tried integrating the expressions and injecting them into each other... but that does not quite give anything (maybe it could be used as some sort of approximation scheme)

Comment: Hint. $x x'+2y y'+z z'=0$

Comment: sorry, I am still stuck...

Comment: Multiply the first eqn by x ad the second by y

Comment: Please add to the question if and how you can make use of the hints. Another hint: What can you say generally about systems $x'(t)=f(t)y(t)$, $y'(t)=-f(t)x(t)$ with $f$ some given function (assumed as such for the moment)?

Comment: The hint leads to $\frac{1}{2}x^2 + y^2 + \frac{1}{2}z^2 = const$, which corresponds to the equation of an ellipsoid.

Comment: @Abezhiko : Just using $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and $y^2+z^2=S^2$ is simpler to use.

Comment: Any (special) initial conditions? Otherwise, i am pretty sure the general explicit solution will contain elliptic functions.

Comment: @maxmilgram added the initial conditions

Comment: So if $y^2+z^2=\phi(x^2+y^2)$, then per initial conditions $e^{-2s}=\phi(s^2)$ so that $z=-\sqrt{\exp(-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2})-y^2}$, as long as this has real results.